# Combine two separate webpage scrapes using the same url into one scrape using rvest and map function

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have managed to compose two separate scrape function that work properly but would like to continue my learning by figuring out how to combine them into one single scrape using a map function from purrr. Both scrapes even come from an index of active pages I call "url_final". Here are two samples of active pages from that index:

```
https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/ken-tabaka-1.html
https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/bobby-adair-1.html
```

I am scraping the name of the player, the height and the seasons they played (season data pulled from the table and taking all of the first column) You'll notice in the second link there is no table. This is a rare occurrence but I put it as an example as this necessitated me using the try catch function provided to me by another amazing SO guru.

Here is the first individual scrape functions that work using the large index "url_final" as the .x:

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)
library(tidyverse)

name_age <- map_dfr(.x = url_final,
                .f = function(x){Sys.sleep(.3); cat(1); 

 player <- read_html(curl(x, handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>% 
  html_nodes("#meta :nth-child(1)") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  .[[1]] %>%
   as.data.frame()
                    })
```

And here is a second scrape using the same url index and taking the seasons from that first table on the page, Notice, you can see from the first url example above it contains this table but not the second URL.

```
player_seasons <- map_dfr(.x = url_final,
          .f = function(x){Sys.sleep(.3); cat(1); 
             tryCatch({
             fyr <- read_html(curl::curl(x, 
                  handle = curl::new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))) %>%
                  html_table() %>% .[[1]] 

           fyr <- fyr %>%
                   select(1) %>%
                   mutate(name = str_extract(string = x, 
                     pattern = "(?<=cbb/players/).*?(?=-\\d\\.html)"))
           }, error = function(e) message('Skipping url', x))
        })
```

I gave it an attempt in combining these two into one map function but to no avail. I'm guessing the solution is pretty easy. I'd like to find a way to map all the data as a single df.

IMPORTANT NOTE

In most cases, there will be multiple seasons scraped per player which I'm thinking might be why I'm having issues figuring this out. IDEALLY, I only need the most recent year that table shows. For example, the first URL sample I provided (Ken Tabaka profile page) I really am only interested in keeping "1970/71" 1969-70 is not needed and will be filtered out later anyway.

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi Jeff, in what way do you want to combine the outputs of the two functions?

Comment: @Bas ideally, a data frame or tibble. A list would at least be acceptable too if that's necessary.

Comment: @Ronak provided an answer below. One small tip: you use `html_nodes` and therafter select the first element with `.[[1]]`, this can be mitigated by instead using `html_node` (singular), which automatically selects the first one.

Comment: Hi Jeff, the below answer worked for me without any error on R 4.0.0. and `dplyr` 1.0.0. I am not sure if you need to update any packages for this. If it still doesn't work try few things 1) Use `map` instead of `map_dfr`. 2) Use `list(first, second)` instead of `tibble(first, second)` 3) Do both 1 and 2.

Comment: @RonakShah Using Map instead of map_dfr worked! I have 95k urls that will ultimately be mapped into a list though, not sure this is advisable but I think R should be able to handle it. I'm not entirely sure how to combine all elements of a list into a data frame afterwards but I bet I can research that. THANK YOU as always. You are the best Ronak!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(rvest)
library(curl)
library(tidyverse)

url_final <- c('https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/ken-tabaka-1.html',
               'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/bobby-adair-1.html')


temp <- map_dfr(.x = url_final,
    .f = function(x){Sys.sleep(.3); cat(1);       
    webpage <- read_html(curl(x, handle = new_handle("useragent"="Mozilla/5.0"))) 

      first <- webpage %>% html_nodes("#meta :nth-child(1)") %>%
        html_text() %>% .[[1]] %>% tibble(text = .)
      second <- tryCatch({webpage %>% 
                  html_table() %>% .[[1]] %>%
                  select(1) %>%
                   mutate(name = str_extract(string = x, 
                          pattern = "(?<=cbb/players/).*?(?=-\\d\\.html)"))
      }, error = function(e) 
            {message('Skipping url', x);return(tibble(Season = NA, name = NA))})
      tibble(first, second)
    })
```

Since we cannot have dataframe with unequal length adding an empty tibble with `NA` in case exception occurred. Also you might consider adding the URL's or some unique key as a column in the final output to identify which row comes from where exactly.